# PHP PDO Simple insert does not work

Tags: php, pdo

I am converting all of my query's to PDO, and i'm new to it.
It's properly a very stupid question but why does the following code not work?

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ddd', $user, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
                $id = $_SESSION['id'];
                $name = $_POST['name'];
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO projects 
                                      (group_id, project_name)
                                       VALUES (:id, :name)');
                $stmt->execute(array(
                             ':id'=>$id,
                             ':name'=>$name
                             ));
```

Thanks.

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: I can't see the output because i the code is in a place where it does not have the ability to output errors, otherwise i would have given them.

Comment: Your web server has an error log, right?  That's where the errors probably went.

Comment: It only makes a logfile at night i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection variable is `$conn` and you are preparing your PDO Statement using `$pdo->prepare`.

Change to `$conn->prepare()`

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO projects 
      (group_id, project_name)
       VALUES (:id, :name)');
```

Answer (score 1):

You're initializing a variable for your database connection called `$conn` yet later call `$pdo` that's not mentioned anywhere. That's the first thing I'd start with.